# Oracle.Row insert collides with uncommitted insert in another window, and it causes my window to wait

Tags: sql, oracle

Window A inserted a row into a table with unique key but did not commit or rollback.

Then window B couldn't insert the same row and keep waiting.

How can I set a timeout or 'no wait' option on an insert, so that window B  doesn't wait?

So it leads to other questions:

1. Where is uncommitted data stored?
2. What happens when I commit the data?

Comment: You should search for and read the oracle concepts guide. Particularly look at "concurrency and consistency": https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/CNCPT/consist.htm#CNCPT020

Comment: re 2)  the waiting transaction fails with an error ("unique key violation")

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would say Oracle is doing exactly what it should. What do you expect to happen? Why is the original writer holding the lock for other than a minimal transitory interval?

Anyway this may help to get the error at LOCK TABLE time.
[NOWAIT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9015.htm)